# Should I use OODB for small applications?

Tags: .net, object-oriented-database

We looking to build an application to maintain meeting minutes and similar stuff using .net. I was thinking of using [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/about/productinformation/) or some OODB for this. Is it a bad idea? I am looking to simply create a repository of meeting minutes where users can perform lookups by date and little things like that. Is having a SQL Express DB a better option than using db4o or [Versant FastObjects](http://www.versant.com/en_US/products/fastobjects)

EDIT: This is a small brainchild to track discussions and meeting minutes. I want to keep the app size as small as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you require operations such as lookups etc, why don't you try sqlite instead?

Answer (score 5):

If you have not tried DB4O I think you will be suprised.  It is super easy to use in a .Net application.  You can save any .Net object with a single line of code and rehydrate it with a single line.  Additionally, you can use LINQ to query your objects so searching is easy.

The only real drawback is that performance can degrade if you have a large dataset unless you index the data correctly.  Creating these indexes will correct the performance problems, but they are somewhat complicated to create effectively.

Lastly, be aware that DB4O is a GPL licensed system.  This is a copy left license so you cannot distribute your application to anyone without publishing the source code under a GPL license as well.

All in all, DB4O is awesome in small apps like you are describing!

Comment: Db4o makes implementation a lot easier. Commercial licenses are available for $$$. Also note that there has been a very recent update of the license (more recent than the answer), see http://www.itwire.com/sponsored-announcements/38149-versant-expands-db4o-open-source-licensin

Answer (score 1):

cannot answer without knowing the object/data structures

sounds like overkill, but on the other hand it may simplify implementation, especially if object persistence is automatic/simplified

Answer (score 1):

In all likelihood, the sort of application you describe -- small user base, keeping track of small chunks of text -- will work fine with whatever DB you choose, or even just a directory with text files.  If you want to learn something new, it would probably make a fine little experiment as well.  But I don't see a strong reason to choose an OODB over anything else.